# Javascript wont fire properly on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I made a modal on a website that is loaded with content from another html page using the Fetch API.

**In short, it works like this:** *Click on a modal link. The content is loaded from the link and overwrites what is in the modal. The modal is made visible with css.*

Everything works as it should, except when the link is dynamically loaded. For example, when I go to a new page (which is loaded using the fetch API) where there is a new link to be opened in a modal. Instead of fetching the content in the modal, the browser opens the link on a new page. If I reload the page so all javascript is run again, it works.

I suspect that DOM does not know that the new modal link exists and thus can not run the script on this particular link. How do I make this work properly? Can I update DOM in any way or is there another solution somewhere? I hope i provide enough code for context.

I'm quite a beginner so I do not fully understand everything yet. And I want to learn the basics and therefore prefer any solutions in vanilla javascript.

**JavaScript**

```
var modal = document.getElementById("apparatModal");
var modalContent = document.querySelector("#apparatModalContent");
var modalArray = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("apparatModalItem"));

document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (event.target.matches('.apparatModalItem')) {
        //code that makes modal visible
    }
    if (event.target.matches('.apparatCloseModal')) {
        //code that hides the modal
    }
});

function fetchNewModal(modalUrlPath) {
    fetch(modalUrlPath)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(function(html) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
            var newContent = doc.querySelector('#apparatModalContent').innerHTML;
            modalContent.innerHTML = newContent;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
    });
}

modalArray.forEach(function(modalItem) {
    var id = modalItem.id;
    var modalUrlPath = modalItem.href;
    modalItem.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetchNewModal(modalUrlPath);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="apparatModal" class="apparatModalContainer">
    <div id="apparatModalContent">
        <div class="apparatModalbox">
            <div class="apparatModalTopbar">
                <div class="apparatCloseIcon apparatCloseModal"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="apparatBoxContent">Placeholder content!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- The link that fetch content and make modal visible -->
<a class="apparatModalItem" id="just-a-random-id" href="modals/examplemodal.php">Click me!</a>
```

Also, if I remove the actual href-link from the modal-trigger, the modal become visible (but without the fetched content of course). Maybe the forEach-loop is the issue?